# How to prevent Eclipse CDT from compiling / building again?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I use Eclipse 2023-12 and CDT 11.4.
I experience the following behaviour:
After I compiled a single file I start building the whole application, then it will always compile the just compiled file again.
Similiar after I built the application I start to run the application it would link again and then run.
With larger files and applications this always takes an extra time.
How can I avoid this? Which settings do I have to change?
Update:
There is no hook at Project > Build Automatically

Comment: Is _Project > Build Automatically_ disabled?

Comment: yes, no hook at "Build Automatically"

Comment: Thanks. This is relevant information that should be included in the question. Does the build modify or create files within the project that are not _derived_ (_derived_ is an attribute in Eclipse: right-click a file or folder, choose _Properties: Resource_ and see the checkbox _Derived_)?

Comment: Here is an example of what I do:
I compile a *.cpp file using Ctrl+Alt+C or right-click in Project Explorer and click Build Selected Files. In Console window I see the compiler command line starting with g++ and naming the cpp file at the end. (This cpp file does not have Derived checked) Right after that I hit Ctrl+B or Project->Build Project. I the see the same compiler command line again followed by g++ -o calling the linker. Hitting Ctrl-B again produces no command lines.